# Multiple criteria in excel

Tags: excel-formula

Currently I try to sort the record by multiple criteria:

1. From date column C
2. To date column E
3. Name column A
4. Time column D

it always give #N/A result, if I only sort by first 3 criteria, then I can get the result, is it possible to search by 4 criteria?

[image]

Comment: Your first three criteria matches row 2, while last criteria matching row 3,so match function can't match, that's why you get the error.

Comment: @MátéJuhász, thanks, I use IFERROR to solve the problems :)

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, I think you are looking for the `FILTER` function.

Replace `=IF(MATCH(1,` with `=FILTER(Leave_form!$A$2:$C$15,` and get rid of the trailing portion after the four criteria.

Comment: hi Euler's Disgraced Stepchild, thanks
I use IFERROR to solve the problems :)